# using DataAdapter to populate table

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataadapter

I have a disconnected `dataTable` that contains a few records.

I am using the following function to get the `dataTable`.

```
static System.Data.DataTable ReadSetUpTable(string queryStr,SqlConnection sc)
{
    try
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand()
                          {Connection = sc, CommandText = queryStr};
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter() {SelectCommand = command};
        var dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**No issues so far.**

What I want to know is if there's an easy to populate this `dataTable` into another schema using a different connection string.

For the sake of this post, assume that there is a table with two columns

```
Create Table Student(StudentId NUMBER(6), StudentName varchar2(50));
```

I wish to fill this table with the `dataTable` that I have in the above code.

I could do it using a command Object and an insert statement. For example this code:

```
static int LoadDataTable(OracleConnection oc, System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
{
    try
    {
        var command = 
            new OracleCommand
            {
                CommandText = "INSERT INTO STUDENT (STUDENTID, STUDENTNAME) VALUES(:studentid, :studentname)",
                CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect,
                Connection = oc
            };
        var op1 = 
            new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "StudentId",
                Size = 6,
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input
            };
        command.Parameters.Add(op1);
        var op2 = 
        new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "studentName",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                Size = 50,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input
            };
        command.Parameters.Add(op2);                                   
       /*
        foreach (var row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            op1.Value = int.Parse(row[0].ToString());
            op2.Value = row[1].ToString();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }*/
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                row.SetAdded();
            }    

            var dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter() {InsertCommand = command};
            dataAdapter.Update(dataTable); //This updates the table, but all column values are NULL.

    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Is there a quicker and easier way where I will not have to loop through the records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first block of code, you're setting the `SelectCommand`.  There's also an `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand`, and `DeleteCommand`.

These commands also exist on `OracleDataAdapter` objects... Since the `DataTable` is endpoint-neutral, all you would need to do is create an `OracleCommand` to do the insert, set it as the `OracleDataAdapter's` `InsertCommand`, and call `oracleDataAdapter.Update(dataTable)`.

Will modify this with more details as I check up on them.

---

A good example of setting the `InsertCommand` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand.aspx).  Note that when you add parameters to the command, the last value you pass to `.Add( ... )` is the name of the column you're mapping to.

Because you're retrieving the data into the `DataTable`, but not changing it, you'll need to change the `RowState` of each row to 'Added' before calling `oracleDataAdapter.Update()`.  You'll need to do something like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) {
    row.SetAdded();
}
```

Let me know if you need more code examples... from the code you've posted, I think you've pretty much got the gist of where I'm going here.

---

***Edit***

When you create the OracleParameters, you need to set the source column to the name of the column in the DataTable.  By default, that's the name returned by the select statment, so:

```
var op1 = new OracleParameter {
                                ParameterName = "StudentId",
                                Size = 6,
                                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32,
                                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input
                                SourceColumn = "StudentId" // If that's what it's called in the DataTable
                              };
command.Parameters.Add(op1);
```

The `AcceptChanges()` method is on the `DataTable`, as is the `HasErrors` property (it also exists on the `DataRows`, and `DataSets`, too).

`AcceptChanges()` only tells the DataTable that you've handled the updates to the database... the changes are committed to the database when you called `oracleDataAdapter.Update()`.  The reason you call `AcceptChanges()` is to reset the row states... else the next time you updated the DataTable, you'd be trying to add rows that were already added.

The property `AcceptChangesDuringUpdate` on the `OracleDataAdapter` will automatically call `AcceptChanges()` as part of the update to the database... I don't usually do that, because I'm used to testing the `HasErrors` property and handling those before calling `AcceptChanges()`... however I'm reading that `AcceptChanges()` is called by default on the update now.  I'm not familiar with the details of how rows that are in error are handled, if the changes are accepted, or not.

Comment: @James B - Where do you set the data source of the dataAdapter to the dataTable?

Comment: @James: will `dataTable.AcceptChanges()` effectively set all `rows` as Added?

Comment: You don't... Just like you called dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable), you call oracleDataAdapter.Update(dataTable).

Comment: No, that will do the opposite... `AcceptChanges()` will set everything that is marked as 'Added', 'Modified', etc. to 'Unchanged'.  You call `AcceptChanges()` after you've called `oracleDataAdapter.Update(dataTable)` and all rows were successfully updated (use the `HasErrors` property of the DataTable to determine if any of the rows failed).

Comment: @JamesB I have modified my code. Please take a look. I have been able to insert rows in the Student table, but all of the columns are null. There is no AcceptChanges() method on the OracleDataAdapter.There are two properties AcceptChangesDuringFill  and AcceptChangesDuringUpdate. The AcceptChanges is on a dataRow.

Comment: Thanks JamesB. I was missing the SourceCOlumn="StudentID" in my code. I have changed my code now and the rows are no longer being populated with NULL values.